# Compilation error on antlr3 files in Eclipse 2022-09

Tags: eclipse, maven, antlr, m2eclipse, antlr3

**Eclipse version:** 2022-09

**Eclipse m2e version:** 2.0.4

**antlr version**: 3

**antlr3-maven-plugin:** 3.5.3

I have a project with a `Logic.g` file. Everything was working OK on a previous version of Eclipse (where I had installed an [m2e antlr connector](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-antlr/0.15.0/N/)), meaning the file would be converted to target/generated-sources/antlr3 (`LogicLexer.java` and `LogicParser.java`), and somehow be picked up by Eclipse and compile a `Logic.tokens` file in target, and the `LogicLexer.class` and `LogicParser.class` within target.

In Eclipse 2022-09 however, my test classes that use either `LogicLexer` or `LogicParser` yield a compilation error in Errors "*cannot be resolved to a type*".

It's just a problem in Eclipse (nothing changed in the code, and a maven verify works correctly).

The tokens file and the .class are being generated as long as I have the `lifecycleMappingMetadata` configured (see snippet below).

**Question:** How can I make the Eclipse project **see** these compiled classes and remove the compilation errors?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>antlr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
      only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[3.5.3,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>antlr</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <execute>
                  <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                </execute>
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: I would simple say the connector you are using is simply too old (2014!!) while Eclipse is of 2022??  Furthermore why still using antlr3 instead of antlr 4???

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not using the connector (precisely because it's too old, doesn't work on m2e 2.x). Using antlr3 because the code was from antlr3 time. Needs to be updated, but cannot update prior to a release just because of an Eclipse problem. It's a major upgrade, needs to be handled carefully.

Comment: Why do you need Eclipse for a release upgrade? If you build works with Maven???